# Optimize summation code

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization

Its from an interview:

```
int fn(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = 0; 
    for (int i = a * 4; i > 0; i--)
    {
        sum += b * i * i;
    } 
    return sum;
}
```

How can this code be further optimized? I know there is a summation formula, but I dont think memorizing such formulas is what the interviewer want. So, how would you optimize it?

Edit: Thank you chqrlie, faivvy, asimes and Ap31 for the suggestions and answers. So i guess there will be three ways of optimizing it for now:

1. Instead of multiplying b in every iteration, we can do it at the return.
2. Replace the for loop with a formula: n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6 * b.
   [A simple derivation](http://yaikhom.com/2012/09/09/sum-of-squares.html)
3. Use loop unroll. Please see the post made by asimes.

Among these three answers, I probably will go for 1 and 3, as they can be applied to all types of codes with similar structure. You should mention there is a formula can be used as a bonus but I doubt if formulas are what the interviewers want.

Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: remove the `b*` out of `b*i*i` and then `return sum*b`

Comment: Perhaps they didn't care about having it memorized, but they only wanted you to say that the formula exists and it can be easily researched. Bonus points, derive the formula or at least write the summation expression which needs simplification.

Comment: Did they assume `a` would always be positive? Also, are you familiar with loop unrolling?

Comment: I would optimise it using the summation formula.   In an interview, if I knew there was a summation formula but couldn't recall it offhand, I'd mention I'm aware there is such as thing and how I would go about finding it (e.g. what references I would check).    Problem solving doesn't require knowing all the answers.   It requires knowing how to obtain or to work out suitable solutions.

Comment: @SIR_Vampire: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @faivvy in his answer, you could try to completely do away with the for loop

However, another approach (which correctly handles negative `a`) is to perform a loop unroll, I will call that function `fnUnroll`. If you are not familiar with loop unrolling, the idea is to reduce the number of iterations and sum the values in parallel

As mentioned in the comments, each iteration does not need to multiply by `b`, that can be done at the end. I added another function named `fnUnrollNoMult` to show this

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int fn(int a, int b) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = a * 4; i > 0; i--)
        sum += b * i * i;
    return sum;
}

int fnUnroll(int a, int b) {
    // Set up some number of accumulators, I picked 4
    int sum0 = 0;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    int sum3 = 0;

    int i = 1;
    int limit = a * 4;

    // Sum 4 values in parallel
    for ( ; i < limit; i += 4) {
        sum0 += b * i * i;
        sum1 += b * (i + 1) * (i + 1);
        sum2 += b * (i + 2) * (i + 2);
        sum3 += b * (i + 3) * (i + 3);
    }

    // Handle the remainder (if any)
    for ( ; i < limit; i++)
        sum0 += b * i + i;

    // Sum the accumulators
    return sum0 + sum1 + sum2 + sum3;
}

int fnUnrollNoMult(int a, int b) {
    int sum0 = 0;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    int sum3 = 0;

    // Remove b from the loops
    int i = 1;
    int limit = a * 4;
    for ( ; i < limit; i += 4) {
        sum0 += i * i;
        sum1 += (i + 1) * (i + 1);
        sum2 += (i + 2) * (i + 2);
        sum3 += (i + 3) * (i + 3);
    }
    for ( ; i < limit; i++)
        sum0 += i + i;

    // Handle b here
    return b * (sum0 + sum1 + sum2 + sum3);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Expects two arguments: a and b
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <int> <int>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);

    // This is just to demonstrate correctness
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            if (
                fn(i, j) != fnUnroll(i, j) ||
                fn(i, j) != fnUnrollNoMult(i, j)
            ) {
                std::cout << "Not equal: " << i << ", " << j << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }

    // Benchmark
    using namespace std::chrono;
    {
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        int result = fn(a, b);
        auto stop  = high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "fn value:             " << result << std::endl;
        std::cout << "fn nanos:             " << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(stop - start).count() << std::endl;
    }
    {
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        int result = fnUnroll(a, b);
        auto stop  = high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "fnUnroll value:       " << result << std::endl;
        std::cout << "fnUnroll nanos:       " << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(stop - start).count() << std::endl;
    }
    {
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        int result = fnUnrollNoMult(a, b);
        auto stop  = high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "fnUnrollNoMult value: " << result << std::endl;
        std::cout << "fnUnrollNoMult nanos: " << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(stop - start).count() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program below expects two arguments which represent `a` and `b`. Below I compiled the program as `g++ -std=c++14 foo.cpp -O3` and have these results for some `a` values:

```
./a.out 1 2
fn value:             60
fn nanos:             373
fnUnroll value:       60
fnUnroll nanos:       209
fnUnrollNoMult value: 60
fnUnrollNoMult nanos: 157
./a.out 1000 2
fn value:             -267004960
fn nanos:             3509
fnUnroll value:       -267004960
fnUnroll nanos:       2820
fnUnrollNoMult value: -267004960
fnUnrollNoMult nanos: 1568
./a.out 1000000 2
fn value:             -619707648
fn nanos:             3137685
fnUnroll value:       -619707648
fnUnroll nanos:       2387840
fnUnrollNoMult value: -619707648
fnUnrollNoMult nanos: 1220519
```

Comment: Impressive work... but an obvious case of premature optimisation: the function computes b times the sum of squares up to and including 4*a. The loop can be turned into a simple expression.

Comment: @chqrlie, How would an expression handle `a = -1`?

Comment: How about a ternary operator? Or, for readability, a single `if` test.

Comment: @chqrlie, I don't think I am following what you are saying, can you explain in more detail? I thought you were getting at something like what faivvy showed but now I am confused

Comment: `fn` returns `0` if `a` is negative or 0: a single `if` handles all negative values (except those that cause arithmetic overflow, which is undefined behavior anyway).

Comment: @chqrlie, It is not undefined behavior, it is overflow

Comment: In C, it is:  ***C11 3.4.3:** Example: An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.*  Overflow on unsigned arithmetic operations is defined but overflow on **signed** integer operations is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

formula: 1*1+2*2+...+n*n = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6

```
int fn(int a, int b)
{
    a <<= 2;
    return (a*(a + 1)*((a << 1) + 1) / 6) * b;
}
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: this is not equivalent to the original code, e.g. `a` could be negative. Also explicit bit shifts look kinda unnecessary in this day and age

Comment: @Ap31 Yes, it is not equivalent to the original code. From the angle of programming, we should consider the negative case. But he just asks for optimization and a formula and I will show a direction.

Comment: okay well how about  the overflow case? your multiplication could easily go out of bounds, perhaps it's better not to do `a <<= 2` beforehand

Comment: @Ap31 Even following his code `sum += b*i*i;`, it still easily gets overflow. I mean he must know some conditions like **a<100** before he writes down such code.

Comment: no, it doesn't matter if the original code overflows - what matters is that if the original code worked for specific values of `a` and `b`, your code should work for them too - and this is not the case

Comment: @Ap31: the case of overflow is moot: arithmetic overflow on signed integer expressions is undefined behavior in C.  The direct expression would actually make it easier to detect and report potential overflow.

Comment: @Ap31: it matters if the original code overflows: both the summation and the formula would fail.  But the formula can overflow and produce incorrect results in cases where the summation would not.  This problem can be addressed, but many unsuspecting programmers would miss it. Optimisation is a difficult art...  I doubt the examiner had all these implications in mind, but a candidate who would point them out and give a complete study would be hired on the spot.

Comment: @chqrlie if the original code overflowed, it produced UB (as you've noticed). Since UB can mean anything, there are no implications for the optimization in this case, i.e. for the inputs that produced UB originally, your optimized code can do anything - including, but not limited to, having UB itself

Comment: @Ap31: I agree, but as you noted, it is important for the optimized code to produce the correct result for all cases where the original code does not overflow, which requires careful handling of intermediary results.

Answer (score 3):

The function `fn` computes `b` times the sum of squares up to and including `4*a` unless `a` is negative.

The sum of squares from `1` to `n` can be computed as **n(n+1)(2n+1)/6**.

Here is a C translation:

```
int fn(int a, int b) {
    if (a <= 0 || b == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int n = a * 4;
        return n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6 * b;
    }
}
```

As noted by Ap31, clang is shrewd enough to detect the loop optimisation and turns the original function into a direct computation, but it compiles the above code to a [much more compact 16 assembly instructions](https://godbolt.org/g/B0mmbe) (against 36 for the original code).

To avoid a potential overflow on the intermediary result, here is a slightly different formula that does not compute larger intermediary results:

```
int fn(int a, int b) {
    if (a <= 0 || b == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (a % 3 == 0)
            return (a / 3) * (4 * a + 1) * (8 * a + 1) * b * 2;
        else
            return (4 * a + 1) * (8 * a + 1) / 3 * a * b * 2;
    }
}
```

A simpler alternative if type `long long` is larger than `int` is this:

```
int fn(int a, int b) {
    if (a <= 0 || b == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        unsigned long long n = a * 4;
        return (int)(n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6 * b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good lord, I should keep my comments to myself late at night. My bad

Comment: as I've mentioned in comments to my answer, this is not exactly equivalent to the original due to possible overflow in the multiplication, but your answer looks really nice otherwise

Comment: @Ap31: you are raising a valid point: the intermediary result `n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1)` could overflow before the division by 6 and the subsequent multiplication by `b`. Depending on the value of `b`, some values of `a` can produce an erroneous result where the summation would not.  There are 2 ways to fix this problem: use `long long` or `unsigned long long` for the intermediary computation, which would still be much faster than summing but could be insufficient if `sizeof(int)==sizeof(long long)`, or find a different formula that does not have a larger intermediary result.

Answer (score 2):

The interviewer of course expects the optimization from @faivvy (and @chqrlie) answers, you can always derive the formula or just say that you know that it exists and you can get rid of the loop completely.

Don't forget about some usual pifalls: `a` could be negative, `a*a*(2*a + 1)` could overflow.

Another thing to notice is  [modern compilers can do this by themselves](https://godbolt.org/g/DFXGCs) - you can mention that to the interviewer too.

Comment: I don't know if that's what the interviewer expected. If I was in his place, I wouldn't. But then again, I also wouldn't have asked this dumb question to begin with.

Comment: clang is indeed impressive, but the programmer can still do better with some thinking: https://godbolt.org/g/B0mmbe

Comment: @chqrlie again, your solution can overflow on the multiplication where the original code worked. clang's optimization accounts for that